# How to write the names "iPhone", "iPad", etc. in all capital letters?

Tags: apple-inc

Just curious about whether it is iPHONE, IPHONE, or just never written in all capital letters. Is there a style guide or something on this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As initially mentioned by Neil, the [*Apple Publications Style Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/APStyleGuide/APSG_2009.pdf) is the place to look.

From page 34:

> - *What to capitalize:* Follow these rules when you use title-style capitalization.
>     Capitalize every word except:
>
>   - Articles (*a, an, the*), unless an article is the first word or follows a colon
>   - Coordinating conjunctions (*and, but, or, nor, for, yet*, and *so*)
>   - The word *to* in infinitives (*How to Start Your Printer*)
>   - The word *as*, regardless of the part of speech
>   - **Words that always begin with a lowercase letter, such as *iPod* and *iTunes***
>   - Prepositions of four letters or fewer (*at, by, for, from, in, into, of, off, on, onto, out, over, to, up*, and *with*), except when the word is part of a verb phrase or is used as another part of speech (such as an adverb, adjective, noun, or verb).
>       Starting Up the Computer
>       Logging In to the Server
>       Getting Started with Your MacBook Pro

That is, the *i* in words like iPod and iTunes (and iMac, iPhone, iPad, etc.) are never capitalized.

I don't believe that, given a choice, Apple ever uses all caps, although the only specific rule I've found is on page 33:

> Don’t use all caps for emphasis.

Comment: damn, page 33! did you read the other 32 pages?!

Comment: @Cawas - It's 224 pages in total; while I haven't read *all* of them, I do refer to the *Guide* enough that I keep a local copy around for quick searching.

Answer (score 5):

There is an Apple Publications Style Guide, and it says to not use all caps for emphasis. ([Apple Style Guide, PDF](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/APStyleGuide/APSG_2009.pdf))

I can't recall ever seeing all-capital letters in an Apple publication. In the design world, all-capital letters are generally considered hard to read and, in most fonts, ugly, so it's my guess that Apple would avoid the use of all-caps.

Comment: I actually have an interesting example. Take a look at the bottom left hand side of http://www.apple.com/ipod/, and see also http://www.apple.com/ipod/red/. It's their only product name that is pure caps.

Comment: @VxJason - that's because Apple didn't name it; they're just licensees. Wikipedia has a good article about the [(PRODUCT)RED brand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_Red) if you want to know more.

Comment: Heh. Only on a Mac site would people be concerned with stuff like this... how awesome. :)

Answer (score -1):

The only official name is "iPhone". If you are putting it in capitals, it is just a matter of choice whether the initial `i` is uppercase or lowercase. Personally, I think it looks better as "iPHONE".

Comment: I suppose it is ultimately a matter of choice, but since Apple gives you guidance on this sort of thing as noted above, it would seem strange not to follow it.